# How to loop workflows with a counter in Oozie using HUE 3.11?

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I have a workflow that starts with a shell script node that accepts a numeric parameter and it directs into different hive scripts using this parameter. How do I loop this workflow so it would execute based on a range of number as the parameter?

What I do right now is I change parameter in the GUI, execute, wait for it to finish, then change the parameter for the next number and rerun again.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using sub-flow, read the following blog to understand how to implement http://www.helmutzechmann.com/2015/04/23/oozie-loops/

The shell action output can be captured and accessed by the other action
 ${wf:actionData('shellAction')['variablename']}

Hope this helps.

-Ravi

Comment: I saw this while Googling for the possible answers - what node should I add in the workflow wherein I could write this code?